# "GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch.h" file not found in "aporat/SocialAccounts" framwork

Tags: ios, cocoapods, social-framework

After I installed [SocialAccounts](https://github.com/aporat/SocialAccounts) into the example "SocialAccountsSample",
XCode said "GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch.h" file not found.

[image: screen shot 2013-12-20 at 4 51 50 pm]

And here is what I get after installed the pod.

"[!] The target `SocialAccountsSample [Debug]` overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The target `SocialAccountsSample [Debug - Release]` overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target."

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you have provided the Library path in HeaderSearch path in BuildSettings.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the correct way.
But there are more problem after I provided the Library path. :p